# if check box is checked display div

Tags: jquery, html, input, checkbox, toggle

I'm trying to build something like wordpress options for toggling fields visibility when creating and article. What I've build is relying on the `$.click` function that is toggling the parent with the corresponding field name and I was wondering what would be the best way of doing this with if the check box is checked because my code will mess up if you check a box and reload the page because its a click and not if the box is actually checked. Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/zgrRd/1/

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="title">
<span class="caption">Title</span>

<div class="hidden">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <span class="caption">Lorem</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    var item = $(this).attr('name');
    $('input[name="'+item+'"][type="text"]').parent().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. It looks like your script works but you are saying when the page reloads you did the `Title` field to stay either hidden on visible based on the state of the checkbox?

Comment: Your input element is not correctly closed you should close it using `/>`

Comment: I have it working but say if I check the box and reload the page the checkbox stays checked but the input div is gone, and and my doctype is `HTML5` you don't need the `/`

Comment: Based on your example in jsFiddle you are hidding the input field when then checkbox is checked so if onreload the checkbox is still checked shouldn't the input field still be hidden?

Comment: @ToddB I'm hiding the input field when the checkbox is clicked which is the issue it's not relying on if its checked or not, here a live link of it, I guess with jsFiddle you can't really reload.. [here](http://layzellmediagroup.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you are externally controlling the checked state of your checkboxes...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zgrRd/5/

In other words, whatever state the checkboxes are in will be evaluated when the page loads, so if a box is not checked, the corresponding element will start out hidden. So if you are setting a value server-side which checks the box, this client-side JavaScript should evaluate it properly.

### JavaScript

```
function evaluate(){
    var item = $(this);
    var relatedItem = $("#" + item.attr("data-related-item")).parent();

    if(item.is(":checked")){
        relatedItem.fadeIn();
    }else{
        relatedItem.fadeOut();   
    }
}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(evaluate).each(evaluate);
```

### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" data-related-item="title1">
<span class="caption">Title</span>

<div class="hidden">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <input type="text" id="title1">
  <span class="caption">Lorem</span>
</div>
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" data-related-item="title2" checked>
<span class="caption">Title</span>

<div class="hidden">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <input type="text" id="title2">
  <span class="caption">Lorem</span>
</div>
```

Note my use of `data-*` attributes. This avoids using the `name` attribute of one field to indicate a relationship to another field. You can legally name these attributes whatever you want, as long as they are prefixed with `data-`.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you could reference `this` as the checkbox within your evaluation method, and chain your binding and initial evaluation together like so: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(evaluate).each(evaluate);`

Comment: @Richard - good suggestion; I've incorporated it into an updated example.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very smart to use `data`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this, [Jquery UI Save State Using Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060539/jquery-ui-save-state-using-cookie), is the missing part you are after to control state between reloads?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxShowHide"/><label for="cbxShowHide">Show/Hide</label>
<div id="block">Some text here</div>
```

css

```
#block{display:none;background:#eef;padding:10px;text-align:center;}
```

javascript / jquery

```
$('#cbxShowHide').click(function(){
this.checked?$('#block').show(1000):$('#block').hide(1000); //time for show
});
```